# Using fabric8 java library : getting error while copying the file from one pod to another pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, fabric8

I am building springboot application using fabric8 java client library. I have use case to copy a file from this spring service pod to another pod running in the same namespace. This is working fine when I run it in my local, but facing below issue while execute in the kubernetes.
Please note that, I am create jobs and list pods but only facing issue while copying the files

```
 cluster`2023-10-17T05:35:36.844Z ERROR 1 --- [//10.96.0.1/...] i.f.k.c.d.i.ExecWebSocketListener        : Exec Failure

io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.WebSocketHandshakeException: null
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.http.StandardHttpClient.lambda$buildWebSocket$17(StandardHttpClient.java:240) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147) ~[na:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.AsyncUtils.lambda$retryWithExponentialBackoff$3(AsyncUtils.java:90) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147) ~[na:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpWebSocketImpl$1.onFailure(OkHttpWebSocketImpl.java:88) ~[kubernetes-httpclient-okhttp-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.kt:592) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$connect$1.onResponse(RealWebSocket.kt:174) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: waiting here
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReady(Utils.java:174) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReadyOrFail(Utils.java:185) ~[kubernetes-client-api-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.setupConnectionToPod(PodOperationsImpl.java:382) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.exec(PodOperationsImpl.java:288) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUpload.upload(PodUpload.java:90) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUpload.uploadTar(PodUpload.java:141) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUpload.upload(PodUpload.java:55) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.lambda$upload$4(PodOperationsImpl.java:427) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.internal.OptionalDependencyWrapper.wrapRunWithOptionalDependency(OptionalDependencyWrapper.java:39) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.upload(PodOperationsImpl.java:425) ~[kubernetes-client-6.8.1.jar!/:na]`
```

I have tried creating the required roles on pod/exec

Comment: What will happen when the cluster autoscaler decides to delete the node the other Pod is running on, and that Pod gets recreated?  Can you implement this work flow in some way that doesn't involve direct file copies into Pods (and probably doesn't involve the Kubernetes API at all)?